# Socket.io with http polling without sticky sessions in a distributed system

Tags: http, websocket, socket.io, long-polling

Is it possible to use socket.io with redis adapter in a distributed system (k8s) with http long polling just for upgrading the protocol **but without sticky sessions?**

Clients will use modern browsers so I am not worrying about websocket browser incompatibility thus I am not going to use long polling as a fallback mechanism but I need the long polling just to upgrade the protocol to websocket. is this possible ?